# How to return all rows with MAX value meeting a condition of another field in SQL?

Tags: sql, max

I have the following `costs` table:

```
+--------+------+-----------+
|  Year  |  ID   |  Amount  |
+--------+------+-----------+
|  1960  |  1    |  100     |   
|  1960  |  2    |  200     | 
|  1960  |  3    |  200     |   
|  1960  |  4    |  150     |   
|  1961  |  1    |  300     |   
|  1961  |  2    |  200     |   
|  1961  |  3    |  100     |   
|  1961  |  4    |  300     |     
+---------+------+----------+
```

I want all ID’s having the MAX Amount by Year. For example, for 1960, I want rows with ID's 2 and 3. For 1961, I want rows with ID's 1 and 4.

```
SELECT Year, ID, Amount FROM costs WHERE Amount = (SELECT MAX(Amount) FROM costs);
```

The above gets me all MAX values across all Years. But I want a condition that only gets me the max Amount values per year. How do I add an condition to only select records with Year = 1960?

Comment: What DB platform?

Comment: localhost using phpMyAdmin

Comment: I only tested two of the answers below, and both worked fine. Not sure which of the solutions presented will execute faster. Other than a stopwatch, I don't have any bench marking tools, etc. Speed is not an issue for me. It's just a one time thing that is done maybe once a month.

Comment: I found this INNER JOIN to be must faster. It does the collecting on all years. I have a follow up question. I have another field that I would like to check. Let's call it region. Each region has a number. I now only wish to pull data that has a region > 5. Where would I add the region check?

Comment: You might only have to add `WHERE region = 5`, but you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks. Tried placing the WHERE in a few places but always i get a syntax error. Will keep trying different things.Thanks for your help. Your INNER JOIN performed fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option which should run on all major databases is to use a subquery which finds the max amounts for each year to select the records you want:

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM costs c1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Year, MAX(Amount) AS MaxAmount
    FROM costs
    GROUP BY Year
) c2
    ON c1.Year   = c2.Year      AND
       c1.Amount = c2.MaxAmount
```

Another way to do this would be to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM costs c1
WHERE c1.Amount = (SELECT MAX(c2.Amount) FROM costs c2 WHERE c2.Year = c1.Year)
```

I expect that joining (the first option) would be the fastest method for larger tables, especially if you have proper indices would could be used.

Comment: I found this INNER JOIN to be must faster. It does the collecting on all years. I have a follow up question. I have another field that I would like to check. Let's call it region. Each region has a number. I now only wish to pull data that has a region > 5. Where would I add the region check?

Answer (score 2):

Try this....It should work

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    costs
WHERE
    (YEAR, amount) IN (
        SELECT
            YEAR,
            max(amount)
        FROM
            costs
        GROUP BY
            YEAR
    );
```

Comment: Perfect. Check it out all looks great. Thank you.

Comment: see my answer which is most faster then your accepting answer. i have tested  both answer. i hope my answer is more helpful for the user.

Comment: @Faisal I agree that this method may not be fast, and is a strange syntax peculiar only to MySQL.  Actually, I think joining would be the fastest method.

Comment: @Faisal please find the explain plan of both queries

Comment: my query
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |       |     2 |    42 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |

your query
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |       |     8 |   280 |     8  (25)| 00:00:01 |

Comment: The cost of your query is 8 and the cost of my query is 7. Hope this helps ! Cheers :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi....I have made this query in oracle and i think it works accross most platforms. I will check if it doesnt work on any specific platform and let yall know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this with below query.This is tested. Its working fine.

By clicking on the below link you can see your expected result in live which you want.

[SQL Fiddle Live Demo](http://rextester.com/BRU30946)

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    costs t1
WHERE
    t1.amount = (
        SELECT
            MAX(t2.amount)
        FROM
            costs t2
        WHERE
            t2. `year` = t1. `year`
    );
```

Comment: @user2140857 if it did help you kindly accept so that others may see it as valid if they stumble upon this similar question it may help them too :) good day

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Year , ID , Amount 
FROM #Table T1
JOIN
(
  SELECT MAX(Amount) Amount,Year
  FROM #Table
  GROUP BY Year
) A ON A.Year = T1.Year AND A.Amount = T1.Amount
```